# Getting ER_PARSE_ERROR for sql query even though same query works properly in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to insert a row to a table in mysql database in express server, using below code

```html
const db = mysql.createPool({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "password",
    database : "user_database"
});


app.post('/orders/new',(req,res)=>{

    const order_id = req.body.order_id;
    const order_date = req.body.order_date;
    const customer_id = req.body.selectedCustomerId;
    const duration_from = req.body.fromDate;
    const duration_to = req.body.toDate;
    const machine_id = req.body.selectedMachine;
    const total_rent = req.body.total_rent;
    const invoice_number = 0;
    const status = "open";
    
    const newOrder = "INSERT INTO order (order_id,order_date,customer_id,duration_from,duration_to,machine_id,total_rent,invoice_number,status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

    db.query(newOrder,  [order_id,order_date,customer_id,duration_from,duration_to,machine_id,total_rent,invoice_number,status],
        (error,result)=>{
            if(error)
            {
               console.log(error);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("success");
            }
        }
        )

});
```

Getting this error :

```html
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(order_id,order_date,customer_id,duration_from,duration_to,machine_id,total' at line 1",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "INSERT INTO order(order_id,order_date,customer_id,duration_from,duration_to,machine_id,total_rent,invoice_number,status) VALUES('101_2021_09_12_16_40_54','2021-09-12','101','2021-09-12','2021-09-13','1',600,0,'open');"
```

However, If I run the same sql statement which is given in error as sql: in mysql workbench by replacing table name with database.tablename I am able to insert successfully.
What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since order is a reserved word,which is the one I am trying to insert,it is throwing error.
Changing sql statement as below solved the problem (adding backtick to table name):

```html
 const newOrder = "INSERT INTO `order` (order_id,order_date,customer_id,duration_from,duration_to,machine_id,total_rent,invoice_number,status) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
```